# Laravel 5 Event Handler Not Firing

Tags: php, events, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm trying out the new Laravel 5 Event methodology.

In my repository, I'm firing the event "KitchenStored" as so:

```
//  Events
use App\Events\KitchenStored;

class EloquentKitchen implements KitchenInterface {

    public function store($input) {
        $kitchen        = new $this->kitchen;
        $kitchen->name  = $input['name'];
        $kitchen->save();

        \Event::fire(new KitchenStored($kitchen));

        return $kitchen;
    }
```

Which successfully fires this event:

```
<?php namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class KitchenStored extends Event {

    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($kitchen)
    {
        $this->kitchen  = $kitchen;
    }

}
```

However, it doesn't link up to this handler:

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Events\KitchenStored;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

class AttachCurrentUserToKitchen {

    /**
     * Create the event handler.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        dd('handler');
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  KitchenStored  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(KitchenStored $event)
    {
        //
    }

}
```

which I know because the dd('handler'); isn't fired during the request lifecycle.

I have registered the event with its listener here:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * The event handler mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        App\Events\KitchenStored::class => [
            App\Handlers\Events\AttachCurrentUserToKitchen::class
        ]
    ];

    /**
     * Register any other events for your application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
    {
        parent::boot($events);
        Event::listen('App\Events\KitchenStored',
                    'App\Handlers\Events\AttachCurrentUserToKitchen');
    }

}
```

Can anyone explain this process better so I can keep going with the cleanest code I have to date?

Many thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In `EventServiceProvider.php`, include the leading `\` when referencing a class using the `::class` notation:

```
protected $listener = [
    \App\Events\KitchenStored::class => [
      \App\Handlers\Events\AttachCurrentUserToKitchen::class,
    ],
];
```

You could also add `use` statements and keep your listener mappings short:

```
use App\Events\KitchenStored;
use App\Handlers\Events\AttachCurrentUserToKitchen;
...
protected $listener = [
    KitchenStored::class => [
      AttachCurrentUserToKitchen:class,
    ],
];
```

Or just use the string notation:

```
protected $listener = [
    'App\Events\KitchenStored' => [
      'App\Handlers\Events\AttachCurrentUserToKitchen',
    ],
];
```

Comment: Using the ::class notation is better, because of autocompletion, avoiding spelling errors.

Comment: @systemovich omg yes... moved a listener and it stopped working, all the paths were refactored automagically except this one, took forever to find this issue because it does not throw an error

Comment: Seems like a great suggestion (I always want to avoid strings) but unfortunately didn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 18):

If you run `php artisan optimize`, your event handlers should start listening.

Credit to mattstauffer from the larachat slack channel for that one.

Comment: Really stupid but I solved my problem by making sure to import the correct classes in the `EventServiceProvider` class.

Comment: Again, like composer dump-autoload, this can definitely be a solution although not the solution for the user right now!

Comment: This did not help. Laravel 7, broadcasting events with the event(new EVENT) → working on staging, but not on production.

Answer (score 14):

I ran

```
composer dumpautoload
```

followed by

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Then my events began firing.

Comment: In a non debug environment, this could definitely be the cause. I totally agree!

Comment: This worked for me. I was trying to add an event and listeners to a custom package I'm writing. I developed them in my actual app, but then when I moved them out into the package, I kept getting a class not found error for the listeners. This worked like a charm!

Comment: yeap, sometimes this is the case :/

Comment: Not working for me. I have straging working fine, but production still not luck running those.

Comment: the second command worked for me thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

Don't be like me and cache your events locally to test something, then forget to clear that cache

```php
php artisan event:clear
```

Comment: Honestly you are a legend!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your EventServiceProvider is calling the parent register function.

```
public function register() {
   parent::register():
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I fixed it by deleting the vendor\compiled.php file. Then I run "composer update" again and now the handler is firing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had the issue where I had multiple listeners for a single event. In that case, the listeners are executed in order. However, if one of the listeners return false, then all of the others listeners are not executed.

Answer (score -1):

This is an older question, but I came across this same issue and for me, it was because I'd added my new Event to the service provider but crucially **I had not imported** it. For anyone in 2020 with this issue, check that you have imported the event.