# Why don't my Laravel 5.2 events work on production when they work locally?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, laradock

Locally, my Laravel 5.2 project works well, including events that are queued using Redis.

> IMPORTANT UPDATE: I later discovered that this premise was incorrect (and my events don't use Redis), and so I'd accidentally posted this question in a misleading way. I hope my ridiculously long struggle and my answer below will be helpful to someone else who is an events newbie too.

But I've deployed my project to a production server (where I'm using a Laradock Docker setup).

There, on production, Redis works for caching and for delayed dispatching of jobs.

So I know that my Redis setup is good.

But *events* don't work (even though they worked when my project was on my local computer).

My question is not a duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 event not firing in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446823/laravel-5-2-event-not-firing-in-production) because I'm not using broadcasting and because I *am* using Laradock.

I've also already tried these commands (inside the container at `docker exec -it laradock_workspace_1 bash`):

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
composer install --no-dev
composer dumpautoload
php artisan queue:restart
```

Comment: What's your queue driver set to?

Comment: @ceejayoz Laravel Tinker confirms it is correct: `echo json_encode(config('queue.default')); "redis"`

Comment: Anything you can share about the production setup and laradock that would be useful? Are you using the same redis container for caching and queueing? Can you get into the container to check if any of the jobs are actually being added to it?

Comment: @haakym I assume I'm using the same Redis container for caching and queuing. The way I can see that basic caching and jobs work is via `php artisan tinker` and then checking my PhpRedisAdmin site. I'm new to using `event()` and don't know what to investigate; I just don't see anything happen in Redis, MySql, or laravel.log. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Supervisor is running workers. In Tinker, I can run `dispatch(new \Jobs\MyJob($blah));`, and then I check the log at `vim storage/logs/worker.log` and see that it ran, and also the app behaves as expected. But if in Tinker I fire `event(new \MyApp\Events\MailListUpdated($mailList));`, nothing seems to happen even though the bound MailListUpdatedListener should have called `MyJob()`. So, on production, jobs are working with `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis` and `CACHE_DRIVER=redis`, but events are not. Events and everything work well locally though.

Comment: @Ryan If you're able to SSH into the box running redis with an interactive terminal (assuming it's docker based) you could use `redis monitor` https://redis.io/commands/monitor to see activity in realtime. Alternatively, you could try one of the scan commands to pattern match https://redis.io/commands/scan. Using this you could possibly see if events are causing any activity?

Comment: @Ryan If this doesn't help could you share the code for an example event and listener and anything else relevant please, by updating your question with the code. Thanks!

Comment: @haakym Thank you so much for your ideas. I finally figured out what my mistakes were and have posted below.

Comment: @Ryan awesome - glad you got it working dude and thanks for posting up the solution I'm sure it may help someone else!

Answer (score 1):

My events are working on production now. Here is what I learned:

1. I'd read https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events many times, but I don't know where/why I got the idea that "events" (which were a new concept to me) relied on Redis or cron jobs. **So the entire premise of my question above was wrong!** I was not using `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue`, so everything was synchronous and should have been more straightforward than I was thinking.
2. I think [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633706/470749) about `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan clear-compiled` was helpful (for after each edit of files on production).
3. The main issue seemed to be that a certain database table of mine seemed to have records with weird values, and those records were being checked by the event, and that's where it was all breaking.

   - And I think these records probably got into that corrupted state because on production I don't think I'd started the cronjobs and workers immediately upon deployment.
   - My local environment was working because its table didn't have these corrupted records.

**Hopefully my naive and misleading question (which led to this ridiculously long struggle and this answer) will be helpful to someone else who is an events newbie too.**